# How to mark events in a DataFrame column based on specific values?

Tags: dataframe, mask, fill

I have a DataFrame containing multiple columns, but the one I am looking at is "Rain_Stream['rain_event']". It is currently looking something like this (only longer):
Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan

Where 1 marks the beginning of a rain event and 2 marks the event of a rain event. What I want it to end up looking like is:
Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan

Where every event will be marked with a number corresponding to the order it occurs. Eg., the first time 1 occur there will be ones until the first 2 occur marking the end of the event. (Both the 1 and 2 should be converted in to the number of the event as well). In between the event there should still be nan og 0 it does not matter.

I tried different things. I tried masking it or using forward fill. But I simple can't make it word:??

```
'I tried different things. I tried masking it or using forward fill. But I simple can't make it word:??'

mask = Rain_Stream['begin_rain_checked'] == 1Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = mask.cumsum()mask = Rain_Stream['end_rain_checked'] == 2Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = mask.nan
```

```
Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = Rain_Stream['rain_event'].ffill()Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = Rain_Stream['rain_event'].mask(Rain_Stream['rain_event'].duplicated())Rain_Stream['rain_event'] = Rain_Stream['rain_event'].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the options :

```
counter = Rain_Stream["rain_event"].eq(1).cumsum()

between = (Rain_Stream.groupby(counter, group_keys=False)["rain_event"]
                 .apply(lambda g: g.loc[g.first_valid_index():g.last_valid_index()]))

Rain_Stream["rain_event (new)"] = counter.iloc[between.index].replace(0, np.nan)
```

Output :

```
print(Rain_Stream)

    rain_event  rain_event (new)
0          NaN               NaN
1          NaN               NaN
2          NaN               NaN
3          NaN               NaN
4          NaN               NaN
5          NaN               NaN
6          NaN               NaN
7         1.00              1.00
8          NaN              1.00
9          NaN              1.00
10         NaN              1.00
11         NaN              1.00
12         NaN              1.00
13         NaN              1.00
14         NaN              1.00
15         NaN              1.00
16        2.00              1.00
17         NaN               NaN
18         NaN               NaN
19         NaN               NaN
20         NaN               NaN
21         NaN               NaN
22         NaN               NaN
23         NaN               NaN
24         NaN               NaN
25         NaN               NaN
26         NaN               NaN
27         NaN               NaN
28         NaN               NaN
29         NaN               NaN
30         NaN               NaN
31        1.00              2.00
32         NaN              2.00
33         NaN              2.00
34         NaN              2.00
35         NaN              2.00
36         NaN              2.00
37         NaN              2.00
38        2.00              2.00
39         NaN               NaN
40         NaN               NaN
41         NaN               NaN
42         NaN               NaN
43         NaN               NaN
44         NaN               NaN
45         NaN               NaN
46        1.00              3.00
47         NaN              3.00
48         NaN              3.00
49         NaN              3.00
50         NaN              3.00
51         NaN              3.00
52         NaN              3.00
53         NaN              3.00
54         NaN              3.00
55         NaN              3.00
56         NaN              3.00
57         NaN              3.00
58         NaN              3.00
59         NaN              3.00
60         NaN              3.00
61        2.00              3.00
62         NaN               NaN
63         NaN               NaN
64         NaN               NaN
65         NaN               NaN
66         NaN               NaN
67        1.00              4.00
68         NaN              4.00
69         NaN              4.00
70         NaN              4.00
71         NaN              4.00
72         NaN              4.00
73         NaN              4.00
74        2.00              4.00
75         NaN               NaN
76         NaN               NaN
77         NaN               NaN
78         NaN               NaN
79         NaN               NaN
80         NaN               NaN
81         NaN               NaN
82         NaN               NaN
83         NaN               NaN
84         NaN               NaN
85         NaN               NaN
86         NaN               NaN
87         NaN               NaN
88         NaN               NaN
```

*Input used :*

```
from numpy import nan

Rain_Stream = pd.DataFrame(
    {"rain_event": 
     [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
      2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}
)
```